# How to add class to new dynamically added content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

To be specific, If i load this content from example.php, look at the form class = "aj-c-p" i use this class for sending user comments via Ajax(Code below).

```
<form class="aj-c-p" action="set_comentario.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$publicacion.'">
<input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="'.$profile_id.'">
<input type="hidden" name="dat_fullurl" value="'.$dat_fullurl.'">
<input type="hidden" name="photo_from" value="'.$renglon['foto'].'">
<input type="hidden" name="name_from" value="'.$renglon['nombre'].'">
<input type="hidden" name="current_date" value="'.'Enviado el: .date(d).'/'.date(m).'/'.date(y).' a la(s): '.date(H).':'.date(i).':'.date(s).'">
<div class="contenido-y-publicacion">
<textarea onClick="clearInterval(auto_refresh);" class="b_green" name="sub_com" class="area-nosize" aria-expanded="false" role="textbox" dir="ltr"> </textarea> <br/> <input class="c-button" type="submit" value="Comentar"> <br/> <br/> <div id="name-for-coms"><h3>Comentarios</h3></div> <div id="divisor-tres"></div><br/><br/></div>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$('.aj-c-p').submit(function(e) {

        var data = $(this).serialize();

        // Stop the form actually posting
        e.preventDefault();

        // Send the request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "set_comentario.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('.b_green').val('');
            }
        });
    });
```

So when i refresh the form with example.php for some reason the ajax code doesn't work properly, i think is cause the new content is dynamically added, anybody knows a way to add the class "aj-c-p" To that dynamically added form, is there a way for it?

Comment: Please provide more details to make your question clear.! what is not working.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy The ajax code runs properly when the page loads for the first time. but after i start refreshing the form with an external file example.php to display new comments, it doesn't work. I assume is cause the new form is added dynamically... So i new a way to re-add the class "aj-c-p"

Comment: what will be the refreshed content.? does it reloads the element with that class aj-c-p.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yea.

Comment: *" anybody knows a way to add the class "aj-c-p" To that dynamically added form"* Does that mean the new form *doesn't* have that  class? Look the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this -

```
$(document).on('submit' , '.aj-c-p', function(e) {

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // Stop the form actually posting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Send the request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "set_comentario.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('.b_green').val('');
        }
    });
});
```